# Drupal 8 user_filter_form

Tags: forms, hooks

In drupal 7 i used this hook to implement user filter form (People->Filter). This hook doesn't work in drupal 8. Any suggestions?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function cl_form_user_filter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //code here
}
```

Well, i added this function to my module, but no results at all. Am i doing something wrong?

```
function cl_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  $form['actions']['find_users']  = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Check for users'),
          '#submit' => array('cl_find_users'),
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The form "user_filter_form" you are trying to alter doesn't exist. In D8 */admin/people* is a view. You can configure the view including the exposed filter here:

*/admin/structure/views/view/user_admin_people*

You can still list peoples without Views. When you disable `user_admin people` the user module displays a basic entity list, but this doesn't contain a filter form anymore like it did in D7. Probably not many will notice, because D8 enables the admin views for content and people by default.

Comment: I need to add custom button to this form/view. How can i do this?

Comment: `mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter()`

Comment: I update my first message, could you please check it?

Comment: What issue do you have with the code?

Comment: I just need to add my custom submit button near the "Filter" button on this form.

Comment: Then have a look in the form array where the filter button is and place your button beside it.

Answer (score 1):

This hook still works check the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.3.x).

Use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state instead of &$form_state, make sure your module is enabled and clear your cache.